# Applying Cauchy's Inequality to show the inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been stuck with this problem for a very long time and i hope someone can guide me on how to show the inequality in the question:

Suppose on $|z| \leq1, f(z)$ is holomorphic and $|f(z)| \leq1$. Prove that $f'(0) \leq1$.

I know that we may use cauchy's inequality to solve this problem as $f(z)$ is holomorphic and it satisfies a criteria to use the Cauchy inequality. But i am unsure how to proceed with the question. Any help rendered would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This result is part of the [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).
You do not need Cauchy's inequality here, even to prove the maximum modulus principle (which is required for the proof on the link).